# How can I print directly to printer using jasper reports and grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, html, jasper-reports

Can someone please help me. I'm using grails and jasper grails plugin. I would like to send a jasper report directly to the printer from a click on my webpage. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: In case of using reports in `pdf` format the problem can be solved like in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated)

Answer (score 2):

There is no printing API in HTML5.  You will always rely on the client's browser to do all printing.  The best you can do is open a new browser window to display the report without any of your website's header/footer/nav/etc.  Add a button with the the javascript:

```
window.print();
```

to open up the OS/Browser specific print dialog for the user.