# How to open print dialog after pdf generated?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jasper-reports

I wrote some actions which generates dynamically PDF files. something like: reports/reportGenerator.action

when I call `reports/reportGenerator?param=dialy` it will open the generated pdf in a popup, and then I can press the print button to open the printer dialog and print it.

what I want to do now is to open the printer dialog directly. so when I call `reports/reportGenerator?param=dialy` and **after the pdf file is fully generated**, open the printer dialog. is that possible? (I know the printer dialog can not be skipped)

more info:
action is something like this:

```
sout = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");
sout.write(pdfBytes);
sout.flush();
sout.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a PDF file's print dialog be opened with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript)

Comment: I already saw that question, the accepted answer says probably not, but many answers say yes, tested them but not working, is embed javascript the only way?

Comment: Yes, JS must be embedded in the PDF for this to work.

Comment: @Kossel You can use the java code to print. The sample: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2008/01/17/print-a-pdf-document-in-java/. Another tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694737/print-jasperreports-client-side

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I have no problem generating pdfs. the problem is sending to printer :)

Comment: I thought that this samples is about how to print. Another link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7999792/876298

Comment: I did the question author do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975652/silent-print-a-embedded-pdf), and I get looped in the if.. seems cannot find function print(); for that element :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Alex K I found the answer:

according to [JRPdfExporterParameter.html#PDF_JAVASCRIPT](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html#PDF_JAVASCRIPT)

you can use `PDF_JAVASCRIPT` property to add javascript to the pdf when you generate it.

so I added

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new  JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");
```

when exporting PDF and it worked

Comment: Where do i add this code and how? can you give me some example?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, add property to your `jrxml` file by clicking right on your `jrxml` in the iReport designer and press properties then press add :

**Property name**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.javascript
```

**Property value**

```
this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: true,bShrinkToFit: false});
```

This property will print automatically in the client side, I'd add it and it work perfectly.

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in your loadView blade file (PDF blade file)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> try { this.print(); } catch (e) { window.onload = window.print; } </script>
```