# JasperReport: Is it possible to set Initial Zoom in PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jasper-reports

I have a JasperPrint that is exported to PDF and it's showing embedded into a web page.

**Is it possible to set the initial zoom in any way?**

I know how to do it with POI (by javascript), but I don't find the way to add the JavaScript code in Jasper...

EDIT:

**Thanks to the link of @ AlexK**, I found the solution :)

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream fillPDF(JasperPrint jasperPrint) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try{
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new  JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.zoom = 70;");
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,baos); 
        exporter.exportReport(); 
    }catch (Throwable e){
    }
    return baos;
}
```

Comment: JasperPrint is Java class. JavaScript is client side language invoked in browsers. You can't mix those two.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: if you don´t know how to do it, please don´t edit my question. Like I said I know how to do it with POI (Java too). Your comment is not constructive. Thanks.

Comment: @ganzux You can add js to pdf. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated

Comment: I only took out JavaScript tag and fixed invalid single quotes. I didn't touch your contents.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think the javascript tag is correct. Thanks for fix my question :) .

Comment: OK, won't fight over this. Alex gave what looks like valid answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ganzux. The zoom can be set with help of JavaScript.

The expression will be: `this.zoom = 70;`

The snippet is:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream fillPDF(JasperPrint jasperPrint) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try{
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new  JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.zoom = 70;");
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,baos); 
        exporter.exportReport(); 
    }catch (Throwable e){
    }
    return baos;
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated code, see the suggested duplicated for non deprecated code and solution using jrxml