# How to change adobe readers zoom level?

Tags: jasper-reports, zooming, export-to-pdf

I have a Jasper Report which creates a PDF in Java Spring. I have been trying to change the zoom level for hours and have not been successful. Whenever I open the pdf's using Adobe reader, its 149% (and coworkers is even worse). There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8984107/6891471) which did not help.

I have tried the following property names and none of them have worked

- "zoom"
- "[net.sf.jasperreports.viewer.zoom](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/changing-default-zoom-level-report-html-output-jasperreports-server)"
- "[net.sf.jasperreports.viewer.zoom](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/6577)"
- com.jaspersoft.studio.viewer.zoom
- com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.viewer.zoom

The values I have tried are

- 0.5
- 1.1
- 2

I have checked my Adobe Reader properties and zoom is set to default, and [accessibility](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Acrobat-Reader/Setting-zoom-level/td-p/3621570) is also off.

Comment: Could you add your code? In order to know why `yourExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.zoom = 50;");` is not working for you

Comment: @Villat It didnt work because I am not using jacascript. I have a Java Spring application which uses Jasper Reports to create the pdf, which is then sent back over the connection where they open it using Adobe.

Comment: Did you try something like `yourExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.ZOOM_RATIO, new Float(2.0));`

Comment: @Villat Your answer was correct but the way it was put wasnt working for me, the answer below gave me the correct formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Villat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2127121/villat) indicated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243442/jasperreport-and-pdf-default-zoom#comment102859833_58243442) one way to set zoom level is "`this.zoom=50;`"

You can do this either by indicating it in jrxml

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.javascript" value="this.zoom=50;"/>
```

***or***

by setting it to the `SimplePdfExporterConfiguration` if exporting from java

```
....
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setPdfJavaScript("this.zoom=50;");
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

### *However*

It is up to the reader (application used to open pdf), to decide if it will/can execute the javascript.

For example in standard Adobe Acrobat Reader DC a user can manually turn this off under menu Edit>>Preferences

[image: preferences]

Furthermore, if the reader is already open it seems to not always like to change the zoom level through javascript, my installed reader works properly only if it opens with the pdf.

### Alternative solution

If you are exporting in java you can post elaborate the pdf adding a OpenAction, see [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie)'s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095098/5292302

> ```
> public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
>     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
>     PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
>     PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0,
>     reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 0.75f);
>     PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, stamper.getWriter());
>     stamper.getWriter().setOpenAction(action);
>     stamper.close();
>     reader.close();
> }
> ```

Hence once exported, you call a similar method, if memory allows it you can also do this in memory using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or similar.

This solution is more reliable, but in the the end it's always up to to the reader that user is using if it will be respected or not.