# Print window not coming up in IE and FF - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter

Tags: java, pdf, printing, jasper-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to open print dialog after pdf generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, byteArrayOutputStream);

if (isPrint) {
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");
}

try {
    pdfExporter.exportReport();
} catch (JRException e) {
    log.error("Exception exporting pdf report");
    throw new PrintExportException(e);
}

return byteArrayOutputStream;
```

This is a snippet of a *Java* method that returns a pdf document using ***JRPdfExporter*** - it works fine in all browsers except for a problem with *IE* and *FF*.  If the document is to be sent directly to the printer the `if (isPrint)` statement sets a *JavaScript* that prints the document instead of presenting it for download.

In *IE* and *FF* - maybe one out of 20 times this does not work. The print preview dialog box just does not come up. Afterwards, I can try generating the document again and it works, so it seems like an intermittent problem. No console errors.

Any problems in this code?  I haven't been able to pin it down.

Comment: You should read [how to open print dialog after pdf generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated) post carefully.